# Cordova plugin iOS add file and folder by reference

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins

How do I add a cordova plugin folder by reference in xcode?

In the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#source-file), there's a resource-file tag.

e.g.There's sample code for android and windows but not for iOS:

```
<resource-file src="FooPluginStrings.xml" target="res/values/FooPluginStrings.xml" />
```

1) In iOS how do I do it?

2) I have a few sub folders and files. Do I need to create a resource-file tag for every files in the sub folders or is there an easier way, e.g. set the folder path and set it as recursive?

[image]

**Updated:**

resource-file tag will just place it in the resource folder. And not add it by reference.